# AJAX или Socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, ajax, сокет, frontend

В каких случаях лучше использовать AJAX, а в каких Socket?

Answer (score 1):

Если в общих чертах, то ajax лучше использовать, когда

1. Вам необходима поддержка старыми браузерами. Вебсокеты сейчас поддерживаются во всех нормальных браузерах и в IE начиная с 10. К сожалению, поддержка 8-9 осла - пока еще очень частое требование.
2. Есть проблемы с организацей поддержки вебсокетов на сервере

Для абсолютного большинства прикладных задач вебсокеты лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Socket намного лучше когда сервер должен рассылать свои или сообщения одних клиентов другим клиентам в realtime. С ajax такое возможно разве что когда каждый клиент обновляет свои данные по таймеру.